# Run CMD command

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to run the below code and expect to get a file with the name `abc.txt` with Dir information. I get the Command prompt but the commands are not running.

There are lot's of questions in StackOverFlow which discuss this, but nothing mentioned there is either required or works.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;

Process p = Process.Start(info);

if (p.StandardInput.BaseStream.CanWrite)
{
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir >>c:\abc.txt");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this using CMD from C#?

Comment: Actually, it is just a sample code. I have some other commands to run, but, while trying I noticed that I cannot run even the dir command. So, if this is solved, I hope to run other commands as well.

Comment: BTW, I don't find useful running CMD commands using `Process` when you can achieve the same goals using System.IO classes...

Answer (score 7):

You have to escape your "\" in the sw.WriteLine for c:\

just add a @ before like this:

```
   sw.WriteLine(@"dir >>c:\abc.txt");
```

*Consider: You may have to run aour application under an elevated administrative context to write to c:\abc.txt*

Comment: I was just about to recommend you to use a verbatim string for paths, but you already edited it. +1